# How to link already made SQLite DB into an apk file or Android application?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ddms

i have made an android application using a SQLite db with an extension .sqlite3 .
my application is successfully running on an Android emulator 2.3.3 and i have put the db in Assets folder and also pushed it in DDMS with the following path =" /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/database/myDBNAME.sqlite3"
Size of my databse is around 4 MB.
When i am using code to copy DB which i found online( " http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ " ) ,the DB is getting copied bt with only 3 KB of it geting copied.
Need an Urgent Help .. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

uninstall your application from the emulator or device, or clear it's cache. The database is copied once. When you run your app for debugging it installs new apk but the application cache is not cleared.